# RANK() in LINQ not giving correct result

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core

I am doing something wrong, somewhere, just not sure where.

I am trying to implement `RANK()` window function in my LINQ query.

Below please find the SQL Query:

```
                select 
                 tl.TransferLinkId
                ,tl.TransferLinkTypeId
                ,tl.PrimaryTransferId
                ,tl.SecondaryTransferId
                ,tl.UpdatedDate
                ,COUNT(tl.SecondaryTransferId) OVER (Partition by tl.SecondaryTransferId) AS DuplicateCount
                ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY tl.TransferLinkTypeId, tl.SecondaryTransferId ORDER BY tl.UpdatedDate DESC, tl.TransferLinkId) as RankVal
            from TransferLink tl WITH (NOLOCK) 
            join TransferLinkType tlt WITH (NOLOCK)  on (tl.TransferLinkTypeId = tlt.TransferLinkTypeId and tlt.EnumTransferLinkType = 'Deviance')
            --where 
            --  tl.Archived=0
            and (
                    PrimaryTransferId in (select TransferId from @AllTransferIds)
                 or SecondaryTransferId in (select TransferId from @AllTransferIds)
                )
            UNION ALL
            select 
                 tl.TransferLinkId
                ,tl.TransferLinkTypeId
                ,tl.PrimaryTransferId
                ,tl.SecondaryTransferId
                ,tl.UpdatedDate
                ,COUNT(tl.PrimaryTransferId) OVER (Partition by tl.PrimaryTransferId) AS DuplicateCount
                ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY tl.TransferLinkTypeId, tl.PrimaryTransferId ORDER BY tl.UpdatedDate DESC, tl.TransferLinkId) as RankVal
            from TransferLink tl WITH (NOLOCK) 
            join TransferLinkType tlt WITH (NOLOCK)  on (tl.TransferLinkTypeId = tlt.TransferLinkTypeId and tlt.EnumTransferLinkType = 'Deviance')
            --where 
            --  tl.Archived=0
            and (
                    PrimaryTransferId in (select TransferId from @AllTransferIds)
                 or SecondaryTransferId in (select TransferId from @AllTransferIds)
                )
```

Below, a simplified version of my RANK implementation.

```
var transferLinks = (from tl in _repo.Context.TransferLink
                                   join tlt in _repo.Context.TransferLinkType on new { TLinkId = tl.TransferLinkTypeId, EType = "Deviance" } equals new { TLinkId = tlt.TransferLinkTypeId, EType = tlt.EnumTransferLinkType }
                                   let duplicateCount = _repo.Context.TransferLink.Where(tl1 => tl1.SecondaryTransferId != null && tl.SecondaryTransferId != null &&
                                                                                                   tl1.SecondaryTransferId == tl.SecondaryTransferId.Value).Count()
                                   where
                                     (allTransferIds.Contains(tl.PrimaryTransferId) || allTransferIds.Contains(tl.SecondaryTransferId)) &&
                                     !tl.Archived
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       TransferLinkId = tl.TransferLinkId,
                                       TransferLinktypeId = tl.TransferLinkTypeId,
                                       PrimaryTransferId = tl.PrimaryTransferId,
                                       SecondaryTransferId = tl.SecondaryTransferId,
                                       DuplicateCount = duplicateCount, //COUNT(tl.SecondaryTransferId) OVER (Partition by tl.SecondaryTransferId) AS DuplicateCount
                                       UpdatedDate = tl.UpdatedDate,
                                       RankVal = _repo.Context.TransferLink
                                                    .Where(tl1 => tl1.SecondaryTransferId != null && tl1.SecondaryTransferId == tl.SecondaryTransferId)
                                                    .OrderByDescending(tl1 => tl1.UpdatedDate)
                                                    .ThenBy(tl1 => tl1.TransferLinkId)
                                                    .GroupBy(tl1 => new { tl1.TransferLinkTypeId, tl1.SecondaryTransferId })
                                                    .SelectMany(g => g.Select((x, i) => new { data = g.Key, index = i + 1 }))
                                                    .First(g => g.data.SecondaryTransferId == tl.SecondaryTransferId && g.data.TransferLinkTypeId == tl.TransferLinkTypeId).index
                                   }).AsEnumerable().Union(
                                      from tl in _repo.Context.TransferLink
                                      join tlt in _repo.Context.TransferLinkType on new { TLinkId = tl.TransferLinkTypeId, EType = "Deviance" } equals new { TLinkId = tlt.TransferLinkTypeId, EType = tlt.EnumTransferLinkType }
                                      let duplicateCount = _repo.Context.TransferLink.Where(tl1 => tl1.PrimaryTransferId.Value == tl.PrimaryTransferId.Value &&
                                                                                                tl.PrimaryTransferId != null && tl1.PrimaryTransferId != null).Count()
                                      where
                                        (allTransferIds.Contains(tl.PrimaryTransferId) || allTransferIds.Contains(tl.SecondaryTransferId)) &&
                                        !tl.Archived
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          TransferLinkId = tl.TransferLinkId,
                                          TransferLinktypeId = tl.TransferLinkTypeId,
                                          PrimaryTransferId = tl.PrimaryTransferId,
                                          SecondaryTransferId = tl.SecondaryTransferId,
                                          DuplicateCount = duplicateCount, //COUNT(tl.SecondaryTransferId) OVER (Partition by tl.SecondaryTransferId) AS DuplicateCount
                                          UpdatedDate = tl.UpdatedDate,
                                          RankVal = _repo.Context.TransferLink
                                                    .Where(tl1 => tl1.PrimaryTransferId != null && tl1.PrimaryTransferId == tl.SecondaryTransferId)
                                                    .OrderByDescending(tl1 => tl1.UpdatedDate)
                                                    .ThenBy(tl1 => tl1.TransferLinkId)
                                                    .GroupBy(tl1 => new { tl1.TransferLinkTypeId, tl1.PrimaryTransferId })
                                                    .SelectMany(g => g.Select((x, i) => new { data = g.Key, index = i + 1 }))
                                                    .First(g => g.data.PrimaryTransferId == tl.PrimaryTransferId && g.data.TransferLinkTypeId == tl.TransferLinkTypeId).index
                                      }).ToList();
```

Below is the result of the SQL Query:

[image]

And the results of my LINQ query:

```
{ TransferLinkId = 1868745, TransferLinktypeId = 3, PrimaryTransferId = , SecondaryTransferId = 44403182, DuplicateCount = 2, UpdatedDate = 2021/08/16 18:23:19, RankVal = 1 }
{ TransferLinkId = 1868751, TransferLinktypeId = 3, PrimaryTransferId = 44403188, SecondaryTransferId = 44403182, DuplicateCount = 2, UpdatedDate = 2021/08/16 19:03:25, RankVal = 1 }
{ TransferLinkId = 1868745, TransferLinktypeId = 3, PrimaryTransferId = , SecondaryTransferId = 44403182, DuplicateCount = 0, UpdatedDate = 2021/08/16 18:23:19, RankVal = 0 }
{ TransferLinkId = 1868751, TransferLinktypeId = 3, PrimaryTransferId = 44403188, SecondaryTransferId = 44403182, DuplicateCount = 1, UpdatedDate = 2021/08/16 19:03:25, RankVal = 1 }
```

The DuplicateCount calculates correctly, but I seem to be doing something wrong with the RankVal.

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Maybe better to get [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) and use Window Functions in LINQ? It should be much faster than emulating them.

Comment: What version of EF Core are you using? You can use `FromSqlRaw`/`FromSqlInterpolated` and do not rewrite the query.

Comment: Also you can try [ELINQ](https://try.entitylinq.com/)